# How do you organise open-source Visual Studio projects with open-source dependencies?

Tags: c#, github, open-source, projects-and-solutions

I've started an open source MVC4 project that is using some other open source project as a dependency. I've forked the other project and will be modifying it according to my needs. The problem I'm facing is how to keep these projects depending on each other, but maintained separately. Yet people who git pull my project, would get the dependency project as well?

1. I can slam all the related code from other project into my repository, but this way I won't be able to contribute to a fork of dependent project. I'll just become a part of my repository. Not really want to do that.
2. I can maintain other project completely separately and copy *.dll files into my project. And commit dependent dll files into git. This is nice, but I loose ability to develop two projects at the same time, along with stepping into dependent code on debug (well, maybe not if copy *.pdb files along)
3. Similar to point 2, I can build nuget packages from dependent project and add them to my main project - again, can't really develop both projects at the same time, need to switch contexts.
4. With some magic have a solution file that combines projects from my repository and from dependent repository. On every build, copy dependent dll files to /lib folder and commit them. This way I don't need to switch contexts between separate projects. But the drawback is when other contributors git pull my project, they don't get dependent project, and solution files will likely be broken for them, because it'll reference project that is not in the repo.

How do you organise your code in this case?

Comment: Care to comment on downvote? what am I not doing right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually I use nuget for all my dependencies. When I fork a project I will deploy it on nuget and also on [symbol source](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public). In this way you can step inside the dependency source without problems.

For more information on symbol source and nuget see also: 
[Creating and Publishing a Symbol Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package).
To enable symbol source debug see http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio.

You must also remember to enable [Nuget package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).

With this solution you can't modify source code but at least you can debug it.

Comment: Yeah, nuget package with symbols included, probably the best option. Symbol source is an interesting resource, have not seen it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar in concept to CMake, but entirely within Visual Studio. There's the relatively unknown feature of property files, which can be included by solutions. This allows you to create a file containing only paths to dependencies, include the libraries you can and set relative paths, and then require people to set the appropriate paths for the other dependencies you can't/don't want to include.

With a little bit of work, it comes out fairly clean, and is super easy to automate through TeamCity and other similar tools (each build agent can set the variables to indicate where it keeps dependencies).

For small dependencies and ones that have been tweaked to work with my project, I keep an archive or the loose files in the repository, and use the properties file to reference those. Others have instructions on where to find them and how to edit the paths.

If you're interested in such an approach, I can go into some more detail. It took a bit of work to figure out, as property files aren't super well documented, but is working pretty neatly.

Comment: that sounds interesting. Any links to articles where I can read about those "property files"?

Comment: are you talking about these? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep, those are the ones. I've set it up with two property files: one is purely dependency paths, and I supply them and all of my version information through the commandline to most of my builds (in TeamCity, that works simply by using "system" variables). The other is common project settings for each configuration (output path patterns and the like). Appropriate use of VS' variable replacement in the include/library include paths and the ability to use environment and property variables in headers (passed through the CLI) make for a pretty flexible and well-organized build.

Comment: You do have to hand-edit some property files at first and set up the includes, but it's not complicated, just sort of round-about and not super documented. For an example of how I have it set up, check the .sln and .props files [here](https://github.com/ssube/VoodooShader). Note that you have to import the property file from each project, and in the property file set both the properties (the actual variables) and if you want to use them in headers, a `<BuildMacro>` based on the variable.

Comment: That looks pretty awesome! I'll have a go on that, once I'm back to the projects.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not creating *circular dependencies*, following is an idea:

1. add a new `Class Library` project with a unique name, say `ClassLibrary1`, to the solution
2. in the `Build` page of its project settings, config `Output path` to application output path
3. in the `Build Events` page, add the following line to `Post-build event command line` block:

   ```
   del "$(TargetPath)"
   ```
4. repeat step 1 to 3 but giving another name, say `ClassLibrary2`, and config `Output path` to the source path of `ClassLibrary1`
5. set `Project Dependancies` of `ClassLibrary1`, check on `ClassLibrary2`
6. add all other project as *project reference* to `ClassLibrary2`, leave `Copy Local` with default value `true`
7. build `ClassLibrary2` once, and all DLLs now are in the source path of `ClassLibrary1`
8. add them to references of `ClassLibrary1` and leave `Copy Local` with default value `true`
9. set `Project Dependancies` of application and all other projects which are not cause *circular dependencies*, check on `ClassLibrary1`
10. add references of other projects, from the path the DLLs were put in `ClassLibrary1`
11. set `Copy Local` of all these added DLLs in other projects to `false`

Thus, the project `ClassLibrary1` be a central control of the external libraries of your solution. Each time you `Rebuild Solution`(or just build the application), `ClassLibrary1` copies the latest DLLs add to its references to the application output folder, and deletes the DLL it generated itself named `ClassLibrary1.DLL`. The application and dependencies at either compile time or runtime would use the same version of DLLs, you don't need to do extra deploying or check each deployments.

Comment: Basically you are explaining how to implement part 2 from my question.  Thank you, but technical part is not a problem here. I'm more interested in the workflow. Because this way I need to switch between solutions/contexts and I don't want to do that.

Comment: Why you still need to switch with in this way?

Comment: Because I can't have both projects in one VS solution - it will make the project broken for other people.

Comment: @trailmax: This approach in fact can be applied repeatedly, that ensures you will not break the consistency from others. But since you think this would not solve your problem completely, I'm going to delete it.

Comment: No, don't delete it. Some people might find it useful in the future. But I'm not sure I completely understand your train of thoughts.